# Cloud Recoding RESTful API Error of Agora.io

Tags: agora.io

I would like to implement your Cloud Recoding of Live Broadcasting via RESTful API. I implemented it with NodeJs. Could you please help me why I get an error and how I can fix it?

On the manual,
"Status Code 400: The input is in the wrong format."
But I do not know what is wrong.

```
error: null
body: { resourceId: '', code: 400 }
```

```
    var plainCredentials = new Buffer.from(agoraCustomerId+":"+agoraCustomerCertificate);
    var base64Credentials = plainCredentials.toString("base64");

    var options = { 
    url: "https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/AGORA_APP_ID/cloud_recording/acquire", 
    method: "POST", 
    headers: { 
        "Authorization": "Basic " + base64Credentials, 
        "Content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8" 
    }, 
    body:{ 
        "cname": "190724060650293", 
        "uid": "060716332", 
        "clientRequest": {} 
    }
    };

    request.post(options, function (error, response, body) { 
    console.log("error: " + error); 
    console.log("body: ", body);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Agora's Cloud Recording is an add-on feature so it's not enabled by default, it needs to be enabled on your account for a specific `AppID`. The error you may be receiving is because the feature is not enabled on your account.

**UPDATE:**
Enabling Agora.io's Cloud Recording on your project is now available through the Agora.io Dashboard.

To enable Cloud Recording on your project, you’ll need to click into the Products & Usage section of the Agora.io Dashboard and select the Project name from the drop-down in the upper left-hand corner, click the Duration link below Cloud Recording.

[image: Enable Cloud Recording via Agora.io Dashboard]

After you click Enable Cloud Recording, you will be prompted to confirm the concurrent channels settings which defaults to 50, but you can contact sales@agora.io if you need more.

Theres a getting started tutorial that leverages a POSTMAN collection for quick testing.

*QuickStart Tutorial:* https://medium.com/@hermes_11327/agora-cloud-recording-quickstart-guide-with-postman-demo-c4a6b824e708

*Postman Collection:* https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6319646/SVSLr9AM?version=latest

Comment: Is it's any documentation  in agora.io. How to create token and channel using Loopback Nodejs API..?

Comment: There is lots of different documentation available through Agora's Developer portal. https://docs.agora.io/en

Comment: @Hermes I am getting following error while running this from Postman.. am i missing anything? {"code":2,"reason":"response detail error:2,errMsg:post method api body check failed!"}

Comment: do you have an active stream?

Comment: even if everything is valid getting the error `response detail error:2,errMsg:post method api body check failed!`

Comment: I am getting the error in stop api `404: resource not found` please guide me. what I missed am following the agora.io official doc.

Comment: Please check the Cloud recording FAQs, the 404 issue is common and has a few different ways to resolve. https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/return-404

Answer (score 1):

1 - Make sure you have enable agora recording
2- Check the link and send all parameters.
https://docs-preprod.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_webpage_mode?platform=RESTful
EX: {
"cname": "httpClient463224",
"uid": "527841",
"clientRequest":{
"resourceExpiredHour": 24,
"scene": 1
}
}
You forgot to put "resourceExpiredHour": 24,"scene": 1

More info:

PHP: you need to put strval function

$body = ["cname"=>strval($cname),"uid" =>strval($uid),"clientRequest" => ["resourceExpiredHour" => 24,"scene" =>  1]];

I hope you solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was mistake in `Region` [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrFx2.png) . I used `AP_NORTHEAST_1` but `10` need be used

Comment: Exactly i had the same issue. So your comment figured it out clear